# Why does \autocite not work when in a tabular environment?

Tags: tables, citing, footnotes

I am writing a paper where I need both footnotes and a bibliography and am thus using the \autocite command which does both at the same time. \autocite works fine when not in the tabular environment, however when used in it, it only creates a bibliography and a superscrpit (ex. blahblah^2) without adding a footnote at the bottom of the page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=verbose-trad2]{biblatex}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}


\bibliography{bibliography.bib} 
\begin{document}
This works fine. \autocite[1]{talbotallum2015}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{6cm}|p{8cm}| } 
\hline
for some reason & this does not work fine \autocite[2]{2020Rolling} \\ \hline
blahblah & finish table \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Please extend your example to a full example (there is no `\end{document}`) and provide a suitable sample bib file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

footnotes don't work in tabulars. But you can use the combination `\footnotemark` with `\footcitetext`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=verbose-trad2]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{6cm}|p{8cm}| }
\hline
for some reason & this\footnotemark{} does not work fine \\ \hline
blahblah & finish table \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\footcitetext[2]{doody}
\end{document}
```